# scraping a website using Angular js

Tags: angularjs, casperjs

I am trying to scrape a website which is using AngularJs, there are four radio buttons on the page two of them have 'ng-required=true'. All four buttons are selected but when i click on the submit button it gives error on the radio buttons which are having ng-required as true even when the buttons are selected. i took screenshot and even in the screenshot it shows the radio button selected. I have tried to overwrite validation but nothing worked. Please help here is Html and Code

Html 
This is the public service radio button

```
<input id="publicServiceTrue" type="radio" value="false"
   name="ibrComposite.application.pslfIndicator"
   ng-model="pslf"  target="dependents_section_div"
   ng-required="true"/>
```

Marital Status Radio button

```
<input id="maritalStatusSingle" type="radio" value="SINGLE"
name="ibrComposite.application.maritalStatus"
ng-model="maritalStatus" ng-required="true" />
```

//Casper Code

```
casper.then(function () {   
    this.evaluate(function() {
        $('#applicationReason_NEW').prop("checked", true);
    });

    this.evaluate(function() {

        $('publicServiceTrue').prop("checked", true); // This radio button shows error even when it is selected
    });

    this.evaluate(function(){

    $('#applicationNbChildren').val('0').change();
    $('#applicationNbDep').val('0').change();
    });
    casper.wait(800, function(){
        this.capture('IRS/Third_button.png')
    });



    this.evaluate(function() {
        $('#maritalStatusSingle').prop("checked", true); // This radio button shows error even when it is selected


    });
    casper.wait(1000, function(){
        this.capture('IRS/Fourth_button.png')
    });
    document.querySelectorAll("input[type='submit']")[0].click();
});
```

Comment: Scrap a website? or Scrape. Also have no idea what you're actually asking...

Comment: Please add clarity. Also share your CasperJS code if it's about that.

Comment: Please [EDIT the Question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40793931/edit) to include the HTML and JavaScript. As comments, they are unreadable.

Comment: . @georgeawg you can see the updated question with code now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CasperJS is not Working Well on AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035005/casperjs-is-not-working-well-on-angularjs)

Comment: The AngularJS framework needs an event to trigger its digest cycle. Changing the value of a property of the DOM is not sufficient.. In the case of radio buttons, the AngularJS framework needs a click event.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword inside a `.then` method does not bind to the parent `this`. Instead use the fat arrow `=>` syntax.

```
//casper.then(function () {
//Use fat arrow syntax   
casper.then( () => {   
    this.evaluate(function() {
        $('#applicationReason_NEW').prop("checked", true);
    });

    this.evaluate(function() {

        $('publicServiceTrue').prop("checked", true); // This radio button shows error even when it is selected
    });
```

Or explicitly bind the `this` keyword in the parent:

```
var that = this;
casper.then( function() {   
    //this.evaluate(function() {
    that.evaluate(function() {
        $('#applicationReason_NEW').prop("checked", true);
    });

    //this.evaluate(function() {
    that.evaluate(function() {

        $('publicServiceTrue').prop("checked", true); // This radio button shows error even when it is selected
    });
```

From the [Promises/A+ Spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-69):

> 3.3 That is, in strict mode `this` will be `undefined` inside of (success/reject handlers); in sloppy mode, it will be the global object.

Comment: thanks for ur response but it did not solve the problem as i mentioned earlier that there are other controls in that block which were selected but two of them were not which i commented in code explicitly